# Chrome still showing red https logo even after adding the certificate to trusted root authorities store (Internal-use self-signed SSL Cert)

Tags: google-chrome, https, openssl

Trying to set up an encrypted connection for an intranet site. It's for a small company and not dealing with any sensitive information, but still would like to avoid login and password information sending in the clear. Would also like to avoid having to buy a certificate if possible.

I tried creating a certificate with OpenSSL and got everything set up and the site works over an HTTPS connection, but the web browsers are all showing warning messages. So, I googled around and found that I could add the certificate to Windows' Trusted Root Certification Authorities. I tried this, but am still getting the warning messages and "red x" https logo. Also tried importing the certificate into Chrome through the options screen but no luck.

How can I get my internal machines to trust my self-signed SSL certificate and not show a warning message?

Comment: What is it complaining about?  Something more specific than "red https logo" would be helpful.  It may be that the name on the cert doesn't match up with the name that you're using in the browser.

Comment: The name I'm using in the browser is just one word, in this case "intb", which is also the exact common name on the certificate. I'm accessing the site from https ://intb/ (added a space for this post because it was being made into a link), which loads the site properly, but with the red error logo. I'll paste the error text below:

Comment: Error text: "The identity of this website has not been verified.  The identity of the server you are connected to cannot be fully validated. You are connected to a server using a name only valid within your network, which an external certificate authority has no way to validate ownership of. As some certificate authorities will issue certificates for these names regardless, there is no way to ensure you are connected to the intended website and not an attacker."

Comment: As another note, if I clicked "more information", the Certificate status was showing "This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store." Then after adding the certificate to the trusted root, the status showed: "This certificate is OK.", but still displayed with the red https logo and the error message posted above.

Comment: I would try reissuing the cert with a more robust name.  Perhaps one with actual DNS qualification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Mr. Leahy's suggestion to use a name with DNS-like qualification would work. Here's Chromium patch information related to the error:

http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-checkins/msg/9fe59a981479aa44?pli=1 (r62178)

If the host name denotes an "intranet host", which in the code means one with either no dot in the name or a dot at the end, then it is considered non-unique, and you get the warning. After quickly looking through other patches involving the warning, I didn't find a way to tell Chrome to relax about the warning.

Comment: Thanks.. in fact I did try Robert Leahy's suggestion above by changing the host name from "intb" to "intb.internal" and that did resolve the problem. Would have preferred to use the original host name but it's not a big deal to add the .internal. Would much rather do that and avoid the red https logo.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure this will apply to your question but I had a similar experience a few days back where chrome would show an insecure site (red cross through the EV ssl) 
In my case it was because some links from google apis were over http not https
thus MAKE SURE ALL YOUR EXTERNAL RESOURCES ARE CALLED OVER HTTPS not http!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same issue today and found a stunningly simple solution:
It turns out that a bad certificate override is displayed during the entire chrome session even if the certificate has been validated or renewed in the meantime.

Restarting chrome fixes that.

If the certificate warning is still present after the restart, then You will have to look at the other answers.